# Reading Data using OLEDB from opened Excel File

Tags: excel, vba, oledb

I have an excel file(Lets' say File X) with 2 sheets. In first sheet I display charts. Second I have data for the chart. In order to get data from chart, I need to process that data as we do in SQL like Group by, order by. Is there any way I can use oledb to read data from second sheet using VBA code in same excel file(file X)?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try googling "OLEDB Excel"? Lots of examples will be found...

Comment: Hi Tim, I am already using oledb right now to fetch data but the file i am reading is not the file I have VBA code in. So it works. But I want to read from already opened file and VBA code is also in the same opened file.

Comment: See example code below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of using SQL to join data from two ranges: it will work fine if the file is open (as long as it has been saved, because you need a file path).

```
Sub SqlJoin()

    Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sPath
    Dim sSQL As String

    sSQL = "select a.blah from <t1> a, <t2> b where a.blah = b.blah"

    sSQL = Replace(sSQL, "<t1>", Rangename(Sheet1.Range("A1:A5")))
    sSQL = Replace(sSQL, "<t2>", Rangename(Sheet1.Range("C1:C3")))

    If ActiveWorkbook.Path <> "" Then
      sPath = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    Else
      MsgBox "Workbook being queried must be saved first..."
      Exit Sub
    End If

    oConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & sPath & "';" & _
                 "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"

    oRS.Open sSQL, oConn

    If Not oRS.EOF Then
        Sheet1.Range("E1").CopyFromRecordset oRS
    Else
        MsgBox "No records found"
    End If

    oRS.Close
    oConn.Close

End Sub

Function Rangename(r As Range) As String
    Rangename = "[" & r.Parent.Name & "$" & _
                r.Address(False, False) & "]"
End Function
```

Comment: Hey Tim, I have one more issue where If file is open from SharePoint, it says invalid internet address for ActiveWorkBook.FullName. Do you have any idea how to get rid of that?

Comment: Hey Tim, Sharepoint is just an example, think of any excel file on internet

Comment: You could always save a local temp copy and query that instead.