# VBA - copying values from range in an closed workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to extract a range of data from a closed workbook without opening it due to it's size causing lag and the need to do this several times from different data files compounding the lag.

I've tried the following;

```
Dim ExampleData as "='C:\Folder\[examplefile.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1:$T$500"
With Range("ExampleRange")
    .Formula = ExampleData
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

I understand what is going wrong there as it's simply pasting that formula in there, but other than looping through the entire range is there a way to use something similar?

I've also tried doing the below with FileName as either a string, object or workbook but neither works

```
Dim FileName as String
FileName = "C:\Folder\examplefile.xls"
Range("ExampleTargetRange").Value = FileName.Worksheets.Sheet1.Range("A1:T500").Value
```

Ideally i'd like to be able to do a .Value = .Value scenario but i'm unsure if  it's possible while keeping the data file closed and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you read from a file, that means the file gets open at some point. Even if you try avoiding calling `Application.Workbooks.Open(...)`, it will still be open.

Comment: Query it with ADODB.

Comment: You can use `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` to get the data from a closed file. See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620080/reading-data-using-oledb-from-opened-excel-file) example by Tim. The method can be used for both closed and open files

Comment: There is a function for that: `Range("targetRange").Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro("'\\Path\To\Source\Workbook\[Workbook.name]Sheetname'!" & Range("SourceRange").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1))`